# How to avoid meteor apps being overridden?

Tags: meteor

I deployed my app1 with `meteor deploy app.meteor.com`,and then I deployed my app2 with `meteor deploy app.meteor.com`. The app2 overridden the app1. The `meteor.com` did not do something with this problem? Any  help ?

Comment: you can add a password to the deployment but you would still always be able to over write the original if you have the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
meteor deploy app.meteor.com -P
```

It would then ask you for the password you want to set, if you haven't already done so to do this.